# How to force reload vite in Nuxt 3 project from terminal? Is any hotkey exists?

Tags: vite, nuxtjs3

Sometimes vite doesn't see changes, so i have to stop dev server and run it again. Is there any way to do it by shortcut, like Ctrl+C for stop dev server?

Comment: What kind of issue do you have exactly? HMR should do its job well by default. And no, I don't think that a hotkey like for Flutter/React native is available by default.

Comment: kissu, deleting some files and exports from .ts triggers error overlay in browser on every HMR, i guess it's rather nuxt problem, cuz there is generating a lot of files from certain folders.

The problem is im working with HTTPS locally by custom domain name through VPN and chrome always shows me danger page, where is must type thisisunsafe for continue, its annoying, so quick project rebuild by hotkey would solve part of problem.

Comment: Ah, ofc i tried a lot of guides for setup local SSL certificates for development, but for me these guides don't work :(

Comment: A local SSL would be the cleanest indeed. Tried my solution (available in my answers) or the one in the docs of Nuxt?

Comment: Yes, the manuals didn't help me. But now I gave myself another chance to find a solution and I did! The answer from this thread helped
https://serverfault.com/questions/973446/self-signed-ssl-i-created-for-localhost-cannot-be-trusted-even-though-i-have-alr